# How to change font and text size in gw basic?

Tags: basic, gw-basic

How to change font and text size in gw basic?Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SCREEN](http://www.antonis.de/qbebooks/gwbasman/screens.html) command to some extent.

Give it a try [here](http://www.addressof.com/basic)

Comment: but in screen i know i can resize text in graphics but is there a way to do it in plain text?

Comment: @NaushaadAbbas You can't. Remember that's a DOS (read - console) text which can't have different sizes or styles